# ionic+angular2 with rails backend using devise_auth_token and active_model_serializer authentication flow for facebook access token

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, facebook, ionic-framework, devise

I have built a rails app which authenticates users using **devise gem** . and also uses **facebook-omniauth**  . It works perfectly.

I am now building an ionic+angular2 app that does the same i.e email+password registration and **NATIVE FACEBOOK LOGIN**.
I am being able to get the **access-token** using native cordova facebook login exactly like here

[:] https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/facebook/

Also I am being able to sign in to my account through **email and password** by using **devise_auth_token** . Similar to this

[:]https://hackernoon.com/angular-2-and-ruby-on-rails-user-authentication-part-2-a0c40f427145

Then I am using **active-model-serializer** to get api response like here 
[:]https://www.kollegorna.se/en/2015/04/build-an-api-now/

Tries I have made :-

1> Did this [:] [Devise auth/sign_in api not returning access-token and client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37887389/devise-auth-sign-in-api-not-returning-access-token-and-client)

2>used **koala gem** to gem emailid of the user and check in database and sign user in and send user details through serializer.

But, i get a ***No token Response*** from this approach similar to 
[:] [rails5 api + devise_token_auth: no access-token and uid returns after login successfully via omniauth2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36841894/rails5-api-devise-token-auth-no-access-token-and-uid-returns-after-login-succ)

with just cache-control and content-type.

3>tried to send and match client, uid, access-token and post to '/validate' method of devise_auth_token. But I its only for new token generation.

### routes.rb

```
namespace :v1 do
   enter code here
    resources :users, only:[:show]
    mount_devise_token_auth_for 'User', at: 'auth', skip[:omniauth_callbacks]
   end
end
```

Any kind of help on how to go forward on this one would be a great help.

Thanks!